# Database theories possible topics to research through

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I need to conduct a research on database theories. I want to know what possible questions should I research on which is believed to be suitable when researching database topics for a online assessment system?

I got one questions which is "Types of Databases" where I want to look up relational databases, object orientated databases and online databases. Then is it reasonable to look up each three types of databases individually by looking at their purpose, benefits and limitations? Also is the mysql database used in phpmyadmin actually a relational databases or classed as an online database?

Is there an more questions I need to research through under database theories?

Thanks

Comment: *Also is the mysql database used in phpmyadmin actually a relational databases or classed as an online database?* I'm not really sure what this means... what exactly is an "online" database, and how does it differ from a relational database?

Comment: This question will almost certainly be closed as off-topic, as were your previous two. Suggest you spend a little time reading the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal form is always a good database principal to research, as is ACID.  Assuming of course that I understood your question correctly.